# Program crashes

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to write a code to check a password for an uppercase letter.
When I type a password with an uppercase letter, the program runs as expected (prints out '1' and the entered password).
However, if I type a password without an uppercase letter, the program crashes.

My code:

```
#include < stdio.h >
#include < stdlib.h >
#include < ctype.h >
#include < string.h >
#include <math.h>

int main() {

    char password[100];
    int i = 0;
    int upper = 0;

    printf("Enter a password with an uppercase letter: ");
    scanf("%s", password);

    for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        if (isupper(password[i])) {
            upper = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", upper);
    printf("%s\n", password);

    system("pause");
    return (0);
}
```

The errors:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program:
>   ...15\Projects\ConsoleApplication3\Debug\ConsoleApplication3.exe File:
>   minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\convert\isctype.cpp Line: 36
>
> Expression: c >= -1 && c <= 255
>
> For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure,
>   see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
>
> (Press Retry to debug the application) ConsoleApplication3.exe has
>   triggered a breakpoint.
>
> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program:
>   ...15\Projects\ConsoleApplication3\Debug\ConsoleApplication3.exe File:
>   minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\convert\isctype.cpp Line: 42
>
> Expression: c >= -1 && c <= 255
>
> For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure,
>   see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
>
> (Press Retry to debug the application) ConsoleApplication3.exe has
>   triggered a breakpoint.
>
> The program '[13188] ConsoleApplication3.exe' has exited with code 0
>   (0x0).

Comment: You have an array of 100 character, but you are accessing character number 101. You might also go outside of the string entered since you don't check for the string terminator, thereby accessing uninitialized memory. LAstly you don't have any limit on the input, which means the user might write more than 100 characters to your array. All of these problems leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: And you could stop at the first null char encountered by the way. but the message is funny. How can `c >= -1 && c <= 255` fail for a char?

Comment: And the part of that array not filled by `scanf` is uninitialised, so checking its values is worthless.

Comment: @RawN: This apparently is compiled as C++ code, so the C++ tag is correct, the C tag wrong!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: The lower bound indeed should be `c > -1` resp. `c >=0`. But `isupper` seems to be only defined for the standard character set code. and on x86/Windows `char` is signed.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - the function takes an `int` - not a char

Comment: @4386427 okay but the input _is_ a char. How can it be out of range even when cast to int?

Comment: Should this be C or C++ ?

Comment: Both answers (two of them at this writing) have missed your `scanf("%s", password);`.  That is just the same as `gets` (and `gets` is so bad that ISO C has deprecated it).  At the very *minimum*,  write it as `scanf("%99s", password);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
```

to

```
for (i = 0; i < 100 && password[i] != '\0'; i++) {
              ^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        note: no =     check for end of string
```

You have

```
char password[100];
```

so the legal index is only 0 to 99. Further you need to check if you have reached end of string (aka password[I] != '\0')

A better way of doing what you want to achieve (inspired by @Jean-Francois Fabre):

```
     scanf("%99s", password);
             ^^
             To prevent buffer overflow

     for (i = 0; i < strlen(password); i++) {
         ....
```

Comment: The correct loop would stop at the first NULL character, and not go all the way up to 100.

Comment: This change has fixed the problem (Thanks!), but I don't understand why.

Comment: @Eden 1) Because your are not allowed to access password[100] and 2) if the input is shorter than 100 chars, you must stop when the input string ends.

Comment: and scan like this: `scanf("%99s", password);` to avoid buffer overrun and malicious attack on your super-safe code :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - Correct - answer updated with that part as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change :

```
for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
```

to :

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(password); i++)
```

Note : You are going out of bound if there is no uppercase letter.

Comment: It was the problem, yes. But no point of answering the same thing (but slightly worse because `strlen` runs the string at each iteration) than the current correct existing answer.